# Joomla Article Manager

Tags: joomla, joomla3

The Window where the article must be written is not provided with the Formatting icons bar on top.
"Toggle Editor" at the bottom right of the same Window is not showing.
I need instructions on how to resolve the issue
Thanks

Comment: Can you please check `Global Configuration -> Site -> Site Settings -> Default Editor` and confirm it is set correctly? The default is Tiny MCE unless you have installed another or changed it. Also confirm that the one you choose hasn't been uninstalled accidentally.

Comment: Still waiting for the new Joomla! Stack Exchange site to make it to beta... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla

Answer (score 1):

You can install JCE editor have lots of built-in feature
Its one of the Best for Joomla content editor
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88